# convert dataframe row to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have datarame like the sample data below.  I'm trying to convert one row from the dataframe in to a dict like the desired output below.  But when I use to_dict I get the indice along with the column value.  Does anyone know how to get convert the row to a dict like the desired output?  Any tips greatly appreciated.

```
Sample data:

print(catStr_df[['Bottle Volume (ml)', 'Pack']][:5])

      Bottle Volume (ml)  Pack
595                  750    12
1889                 750    12
3616                1000    12
4422                 750    12
5022                 750    12


Code:

v = catStr_df[catStr_df['Item Number']==34881][['Bottle Volume (ml)', 'Pack']]\
.drop_duplicates(keep='first').to_dict()

v

Output:

{'Bottle Volume (ml)': {9534: 1000}, 'Pack': {9534: 12}}

Desired output:

{'Bottle Volume (ml)': 1000, 'Pack': 12}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try adding `.to_dict('records')[0]` to the row you want

```
catStr_df[catStr_df['Item Number']==34881].to_dict('records')[0]
```

Comment: @jpp Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  When I try adding [0] I get "KeyError: 0".  Update:  If I take the drop_duplicates out your suggestion works perfectly, thank you again!

Comment: so `catStr_df[catStr_df['Item Number']==34881].squeeze().to_dict()`

Answer (score 8):

Use `df.to_dict(orient='index')` to have index value as keys for easy retrieval of data

Answer (score 0):

taking a different tactic, this works but you need to get a list of columns. This assumed you want the index number as a dict item

```
def row_converter(row, listy):
    #convert pandas row to a dictionary
    #requires a list of columns and a row as a tuple
    count = 1
    pictionary = {}
    pictionary['Index'] = row[0]
    for item in listy:
        pictionary[item] = row[count]
        count += 1
    print(pictionary)
    return pictionary

df = PD.read_csv("yourFile", dtype=object, delimiter=",", na_filter=False)
listy = df.columns
for row in df.itertuples():
    rowDict = row_converter(row, listy)
```