# How to convert the Dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like the one mentioned below.

[image]

I want to have a dictionary for all non zero columns from the above Dataframe like the one below.

```py
{
(0, 'aan'): 1,
 (0, 'abcc'): 1,
 (1, 'acd'): 1,
 (3, 'access'): 5,
 (3, 'acd'): 3,
 (4, 'aao'): 2,
 (4, 'access’): 4
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert dataframe row to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575802/convert-dataframe-row-to-dict)

Comment: I am actually looking for row and column pair and it’s value ( if it’s value is not zero)

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Please see [mcve], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pipe it through a sparse matrix and return the DataFrame as a dict.
Unfortunately pandas has limited sparse matrix capabilities, so we need to use scipy. The following code should work for your application.

```
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #for the random dataframe as example.

# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1000, 10)))

# Use scipy to create sparse matrix
coo = sp.sparse.csc_matrix(df).tocoo(copy=False)

# Parse sparse matrix back into dataframe without zeroes.
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': coo.row, 'col': coo.col, 'data': coo.data})[
    ['index', 'col', 'data']].sort_values(['index', 'col']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Create index to split (row, column) from value.
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['index','col']])
df = df['data'].copy(True)
df.index = ix

# Output as dict
df.to_dict()
```

```
df
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  4  7  0  3  4  8  6  0  5  3
1  3  3  9  2  1  2  8  2  7  2
2  0  1  5  5  4  3  2  0  4  1
3  6  7  7  7  2  1  3  7  1  1
4  2  5  9  8  9  7  5  4  0  3
```

```
{(0, 0): 4,
 (0, 1): 7,
 (0, 3): 3, # Notice (0,2) is gone.
 (0, 4): 4,
 (0, 5): 8,
 (0, 6): 6,
 (0, 8): 5,
 (0, 9): 3,
 (1, 0): 3,
 (1, 1): 3,
 (1, 2): 9,
 (1, 3): 2,
 (1, 4): 1,
 (1, 5): 2,
 (1, 6): 8,
 (1, 7): 2,
 (1, 8): 7,
 (1, 9): 2,
 (2, 1): 1, # Notice (2,0) is gone.
 (2, 2): 5,
 (2, 3): 5,
 (2, 4): 4,
 (2, 5): 3,
 (2, 6): 2,
 (2, 8): 4,
 (2, 9): 1,
```

Comment: This solution is perfect. Many thanks for this. Is there a way possible to have the column name inplace of the column index ? Since your df have column name as ( 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 ) so it’s showing that but in real case the column name is not an index number.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, there are two steps to deal with the problem:

1. Get the boolean, whether the element is 0
2. Sum up the value

```
    result = (df==0).sum()
    result.to_dict() # convert data to dict
```

Comment: row and column have to maintain individual values. This will not bring the desire result.

Comment: Yes, this just stat the column non-zero. It's not a perfect method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic, brute force approach. Does **not** scale.

```
data = {'aan': [1, 2,0], 'aao': [0,3, 4], 'access':[0,0,1]}
df = pandas.pandas.DataFrame(data=data)
master= {}
for t in df.itertuples():
    _ = {(t.Index, col):getattr(t, col) for col in df.columns if getattr(t, col)}
    if not _:continue
    master.update(_)
```

Prints

```
{(0, 'aan'): 1, (1, 'aan'): 2, (1, 'aao'): 3, (2, 'aao'): 4, (2, 'access'): 1}
```

Comment: It is giving me an error “  AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute ‘-‘  “. I am using this code.  df = idf_df
master= {}
for t in df.itertuples():
    _ = {(t.Index, col):getattr(t, col) for col in df.columns if getattr(t, col)}
    if not _:continue
    master.update(_)